# JAVASCRIPT: How to track and log user events on a website(like Google Analytics)

Tags: javascript, google-analytics, serverside-javascript, segment-io

I want to create an application like **Google Analytics**. I have taken [Analytics.js](https://github.com/segmentio/analytics.js) code from **Segment**(open source analytics application [Segment.com](https://segment.com)) which contains all the in-built functions to track User Events. I have also added async code to load [Analytics.js](https://github.com/segmentio/analytics.js) into my website. Now I am Stuck. How can I collect those Event details occurring on my website and send it to my own server?

Comment: Please check [How to create Minimal complete and verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 1):

I assume your are [collecting pageview data](https://www.lunametrics.com/blog/2016/06/22/google-analytics-collects-information/) but you are stuck on event data, right? Try using [event listeners](https://analytical42.com/2016/track-google-analytics-event-listeners/) in order to be able to collect whatever action takes place on the site.

For example, if you want to register when someone is using a textarea:

```
textarea.addEventListener(
        'keyup',
         sendInfoToAnalytics(),
         true
    );
```